# Reorder table using js when add more row in the table

Tags: javascript, html

I create a table from a JS to add more row

```
function addItem(code,name) {  
    var tblList = document.getElementById("list_inventory");
    var tblBody = tblList.tBodies[0];
    var lastRow = tblBody.rows.length;
    var row     = tblBody.insertRow(lastRow);               

    var newCell = row.insertCell(0);
    newCell.innerHTML = lastRow+1;

    var newCell = row.insertCell(1);
    newCell.innerHTML = name+"<input type='hidden' name='code[]' id='code[]' value='"+code+"' />";
}
```

But the problem is I need to make a table ascending by 'name' whenever I create more row? Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please share your html code also? It would be more clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. After you inserted:

```
var rows = tblBody.rows;
rows.sort(function(a,b) {
    var first = a.cells[0].children[0].name;
    var second = b.cells[0].children[0].name;
    return (first.name < second.name) ? 1 : ((first.name > second.name) ? -1 : 0);
});
tblBody.rows.innerHTML = rows;
```

So the idea is to pick the rows and then sort it by input name prop. Hope it'll help you.